# Axois Google Map Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, xml, http, google-places, axios

I am attempting to use the *axios* javascript library to make an HTTP request to the Google Places autosuggest API. My small code is shown below:

```
  axios.get(BASE_URL + 'input=' + userInput + '&key=' + API_KEY)
    .then( response => {
      console.log(response.data)
      console.log(response.status)
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
```

If I visit the url `BASE_URL + 'input=' + userInput + '&key=' + API_KEY` I receive a JSON output of the desired results. However, when I attempt to use the above code I receive a very cryptic error message shown below:

```
Error: Network Error
            at createError (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:15)
            at XMLHttpRequest.handleError [as onerror] (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:87:14)
            at XMLHttpRequest.callback.(anonymous function) (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:289:32)
            at invokeEventListeners (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)
            at invokeInlineListeners (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:166:7)
            at EventTargetImpl._dispatch (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:122:7)
            at EventTargetImpl.dispatchEvent (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:87:17)
            at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:61:35)
            at XMLHttpRequest.abort (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:405:16)
            at Object.abort (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:315:13)
            at RequestManager.close (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:146:21)
            at Window.close (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:362:29)
            at JSDOMEnvironment.dispose (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:47:19)
            at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/KG/Desktop/buk-searchkit-boilerplate/node_modules/jest-cli/build/runTest.js:68:9)
```

Any help is appreciated. I would prefer to use the *axios* library in comparison to plain HTTP requests for its promise functionality.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the link that is created (at least part of it) ? Does it contain the schema `https://` ?

Comment: @Titus 

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=undefined&key=`

Comment: Sorry 

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json‌​?input=Dal&key‌​=`